# error while trying to install exim from source

Tags: compilation, centos, mail-server, exim

```
[root@test exim-4.80.1]# make
`Makefile' is up to date.

make[1]: Entering directory `/opt/test/exim-4.80.1/build-Linux-x86_64'
>>> version 4.80.1 #14

gcc exim_monitor/em_StripChart.c
../exim_monitor/em_StripChart.c:40:28: error: X11/IntrinsicP.h: No such file or directory
../exim_monitor/em_StripChart.c:41:28: error: X11/StringDefs.h: No such file or directory
../exim_monitor/em_StripChart.c:42:29: error: X11/Xaw/XawInit.h: No such file or directory
../exim_monitor/em_StripChart.c:43:32: error: X11/Xaw/StripCharP.h: No such file or directory
../exim_monitor/em_StripChart.c:44:24: error: X11/Xfuncs.h: No such file or directory
../exim_monitor/em_StripChart.c:52: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘resources’
../exim_monitor/em_StripChart.c:75: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘unsigned’
../exim_monitor/em_StripChart.c:76: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘unsigned’
../exim_monitor/em_StripChart.c:78: warning: parameter names (without types) in function declaration
../exim_monitor/em_StripChart.c:79: warning: parameter names (without types) in function declaration
../exim_monitor/em_StripChart.c:80: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘SetValues’
../exim_monitor/em_StripChart.c:82: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘int’
../exim_monitor/em_StripChart.c:85: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘stripChartClassRec’
../exim_monitor/em_StripChart.c:126: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘mystripChartWidgetClass’
../exim_monitor/em_StripChart.c: In function ‘CreateGC’:
../exim_monitor/em_StripChart.c:145: error: expected declaration specifiers before ‘StripChartWidget’
../exim_monitor/em_StripChart.c:148: error: ‘XGCValues’ undeclared (first use in this function)
../exim_monitor/em_StripChart.c:148: error: (Each undeclared identifier is reported only once
../exim_monitor/em_StripChart.c:148: error: for each function it appears in.)
../exim_monitor/em_StripChart.c:148: error: expected ‘;’ before ‘myXGCV’
../exim_monitor/em_StripChart.c:150: error: ‘FOREGROUND’ undeclared (first use in this function)
../exim_monitor/em_StripChart.c:151: error: ‘myXGCV’ undeclared (first use in this function)
../exim_monitor/em_StripChart.c:151: error: invalid type argument of ‘->’ (have ‘int’)
../exim_monitor/em_StripChart.c:152: error: invalid type argument of ‘->’ (have ‘int’)
../exim_monitor/em_StripChart.c:152: error: ‘Widget’ undeclared (first use in this function)
../exim_monitor/em_StripChart.c:152: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘w’
../exim_monitor/em_StripChart.c:155: error: ‘HIGHLIGHT’ undeclared (first use in this function)
../exim_monitor/em_StripChart.c:156: error: invalid type argument of ‘->’ (have ‘int’)
../exim_monitor/em_StripChart.c:157: error: invalid type argument of ‘->’ (have ‘int’)
../exim_monitor/em_StripChart.c:157: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘w’
../exim_monitor/em_StripChart.c: In function ‘DestroyGC’:
../exim_monitor/em_StripChart.c:170: error: expected declaration specifiers before ‘StripChartWidget’
../exim_monitor/em_StripChart.c:173: error: ‘FOREGROUND’ undeclared (first use in this function)
../exim_monitor/em_StripChart.c:174: error: ‘Widget’ undeclared (first use in this function)
../exim_monitor/em_StripChart.c:174: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘w’
../exim_monitor/em_StripChart.c:176: error: ‘HIGHLIGHT’ undeclared (first use in this function)
../exim_monitor/em_StripChart.c:177: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘w’
../exim_monitor/em_StripChart.c: In function ‘Initialize’:
../exim_monitor/em_StripChart.c:182: error: expected declaration specifiers before ‘Widget’
../exim_monitor/em_StripChart.c:184: error: ‘StripChartWidget’ undeclared (first use in this function)
../exim_monitor/em_StripChart.c:184: error: expected ‘;’ before ‘w’
../exim_monitor/em_StripChart.c:186: error: ‘w’ undeclared (first use in this function)
../exim_monitor/em_StripChart.c:190: error: ‘XtPointer’ undeclared (first use in this function)
../exim_monitor/em_StripChart.c:190: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘gnew’
../exim_monitor/em_StripChart.c:191: error: ‘ALL_GCS’ undeclared (first use in this function)
../exim_monitor/em_StripChart.c: In function ‘Destroy’:
../exim_monitor/em_StripChart.c:201: error: expected declaration specifiers before ‘Widget’
../exim_monitor/em_StripChart.c:203: error: ‘StripChartWidget’ undeclared (first use in this function)
../exim_monitor/em_StripChart.c:203: error: expected ‘;’ before ‘w’
../exim_monitor/em_StripChart.c:205: error: ‘w’ undeclared (first use in this function)
../exim_monitor/em_StripChart.c:209: error: ‘ALL_GCS’ undeclared (first use in this function)
../exim_monitor/em_StripChart.c: In function ‘Redisplay’:
../exim_monitor/em_StripChart.c:220: error: expected declaration specifiers before ‘Widget’
../exim_monitor/em_StripChart.c:221: error: expected declaration specifiers before ‘XEvent’
../exim_monitor/em_StripChart.c:222: error: expected declaration specifiers before ‘Region’
../exim_monitor/em_StripChart.c:224: error: invalid type argument of ‘->’ (have ‘int’)
../exim_monitor/em_StripChart.c:224: error: ‘GraphicsExpose’ undeclared (first use in this function)
../exim_monitor/em_StripChart.c:225: error: ‘StripChartWidget’ undeclared (first use in this function)
../exim_monitor/em_StripChart.c:225: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘w’
../exim_monitor/em_StripChart.c:228: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘w’
../exim_monitor/em_StripChart.c: In function ‘draw_it’:
../exim_monitor/em_StripChart.c:235: error: expected declaration specifiers before ‘XtPointer’
../exim_monitor/em_StripChart.c:236: error: expected declaration specifiers before ‘XtIntervalId’
../exim_monitor/em_StripChart.c:238: error: ‘StripChartWidget’ undeclared (first use in this function)
../exim_monitor/em_StripChart.c:238: error: expected ‘;’ before ‘w’
../exim_monitor/em_StripChart.c:241: error: ‘w’ undeclared (first use in this function)
../exim_monitor/em_StripChart.c:243: error: ‘Widget’ undeclared (first use in this function)
../exim_monitor/em_StripChart.c:243: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘w’
../exim_monitor/em_StripChart.c:247: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘w’
../exim_monitor/em_StripChart.c:254: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘w’
../exim_monitor/em_StripChart.c:270: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘w’
../exim_monitor/em_StripChart.c:285: error: ‘CoordModePrevious’ undeclared (first use in this function)
../exim_monitor/em_StripChart.c: In function ‘repaint_window’:
../exim_monitor/em_StripChart.c:306: error: expected declaration specifiers before ‘StripChartWidget’
../exim_monitor/em_StripChart.c:310: error: invalid type argument of ‘->’ (have ‘int’)
../exim_monitor/em_StripChart.c:311: error: invalid type argument of ‘->’ (have ‘int’)
../exim_monitor/em_StripChart.c:316: error: invalid type argument of ‘->’ (have ‘int’)
../exim_monitor/em_StripChart.c:316: error: invalid type argument of ‘->’ (have ‘int’)
../exim_monitor/em_StripChart.c:317: error: invalid type argument of ‘->’ (have ‘int’)
../exim_monitor/em_StripChart.c:318: error: invalid type argument of ‘->’ (have ‘int’)
../exim_monitor/em_StripChart.c:319: error: invalid type argument of ‘->’ (have ‘int’)
../exim_monitor/em_StripChart.c:323: error: invalid type argument of ‘->’ (have ‘int’)
../exim_monitor/em_StripChart.c:324: error: invalid type argument of ‘->’ (have ‘int’)
../exim_monitor/em_StripChart.c:327: error: invalid type argument of ‘->’ (have ‘int’)
../exim_monitor/em_StripChart.c:331: error: ‘Widget’ undeclared (first use in this function)
../exim_monitor/em_StripChart.c:331: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘w’
../exim_monitor/em_StripChart.c:336: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘w’
../exim_monitor/em_StripChart.c:337: error: ‘Display’ undeclared (first use in this function)
../exim_monitor/em_StripChart.c:337: error: ‘dpy’ undeclared (first use in this function)
../exim_monitor/em_StripChart.c:338: error: ‘Window’ undeclared (first use in this function)
../exim_monitor/em_StripChart.c:338: error: expected ‘;’ before ‘win’
../exim_monitor/em_StripChart.c:347: error: invalid type argument of ‘->’ (have ‘int’)
../exim_monitor/em_StripChart.c:348: error: invalid type argument of ‘->’ (have ‘int’)
../exim_monitor/em_StripChart.c:348: error: invalid type argument of ‘->’ (have ‘int’)
../exim_monitor/em_StripChart.c:349: error: invalid type argument of ‘->’ (have ‘int’)
../exim_monitor/em_StripChart.c:351: error: ‘win’ undeclared (first use in this function)
../exim_monitor/em_StripChart.c:351: error: invalid type argument of ‘->’ (have ‘int’)
../exim_monitor/em_StripChart.c:353: error: invalid type argument of ‘->’ (have ‘int’)
../exim_monitor/em_StripChart.c:357: error: invalid type argument of ‘->’ (have ‘int’)
../exim_monitor/em_StripChart.c:358: error: invalid type argument of ‘->’ (have ‘int’)
../exim_monitor/em_StripChart.c:358: error: invalid type argument of ‘->’ (have ‘int’)
../exim_monitor/em_StripChart.c:359: error: invalid type argument of ‘->’ (have ‘int’)
../exim_monitor/em_StripChart.c: At top level:
../exim_monitor/em_StripChart.c:373: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘w’
../exim_monitor/em_StripChart.c:433: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘SetValues’
../exim_monitor/em_StripChart.c:435: error: expected identifier or ‘(’ before ‘{’ token
../exim_monitor/em_StripChart.c: In function ‘SetPoints’:
../exim_monitor/em_StripChart.c:481: error: expected declaration specifiers before ‘StripChartWidget’
../exim_monitor/em_StripChart.c:483: error: ‘XPoint’ undeclared (first use in this function)
../exim_monitor/em_StripChart.c:483: error: ‘points’ undeclared (first use in this function)
../exim_monitor/em_StripChart.c:484: error: ‘Cardinal’ undeclared (first use in this function)
../exim_monitor/em_StripChart.c:484: error: expected ‘;’ before ‘size’
../exim_monitor/em_StripChart.c:487: error: invalid type argument of ‘->’ (have ‘int’)
../exim_monitor/em_StripChart.c:488: error: invalid type argument of ‘->’ (have ‘int’)
../exim_monitor/em_StripChart.c:489: error: invalid type argument of ‘->’ (have ‘int’)
../exim_monitor/em_StripChart.c:493: error: ‘size’ undeclared (first use in this function)
../exim_monitor/em_StripChart.c:493: error: invalid type argument of ‘->’ (have ‘int’)
../exim_monitor/em_StripChart.c:495: error: expected expression before ‘)’ token
../exim_monitor/em_StripChart.c:496: error: invalid type argument of ‘->’ (have ‘int’)
../exim_monitor/em_StripChart.c:500: error: invalid type argument of ‘->’ (have ‘int’)
../exim_monitor/em_StripChart.c:502: error: invalid type argument of ‘->’ (have ‘int’)
../exim_monitor/em_StripChart.c:502: error: invalid type argument of ‘->’ (have ‘int’)
make[1]: *** [em_StripChart.o] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/opt/test/exim-4.80.1/build-Linux-x86_64'
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

please help.... i am trying to install exim from source for the first time. but this error occurs when i try to make exim. i cant use yum or rpm because this is a task given to me to install exim from source. thank you.

Answer (score 0):

`exim-monitor` or `eximon` is an X-based tool. When `exim` is configured to be built with `eximon` a lot of X-related dependencies are required. If some required soft/lib wasn't installed - you'll get an error.

To avoid that error just disable `eximon` in the exim build config.

Answer (score 0):

I had something similar on Centos 6 minimal install.  This is what I had to install (as root):

(Mine is a custom build with LDAP and TLS, so there may be more here than you need).

```
yum install pcre-devel
yum install libxext-dev
yum install xorg-x11-proto-devel
yum install libXt-devel
yum install openldap-devel
yum install openssl-devel
yum install Xaw-devel
yum install Xaw3d-devel
yum install Xaw3d
yum install libXaw-devel
```